# Programmatically Use Pattern Matching

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to programmatically pattern match?

```
Pattern = {error, '_'},
IsError = 
    case {error, "foo"} of
        Pattern -> true;
        _ -> false
    end.
```

I know I can do this with macros, but I have a dynamic list of patterns I would like to match that aren't known ahead of time.

Comment: the question is kind of open, there are ways, but mostly depends on what you want to match and what patterns you have in mind, will you just match tuples? maps? any term at all? 
i.e. you can use something like Pattern Matching (5.7) (https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/mnesia_chap4) on mnesia, you still have to code it. yourself, but it is a known way of programmatically do pattern matching in erlang
maybe some sample with the patterns you have in mind will help

Comment: @rorra Darn and it looks like that's specific to mnesia/ets/dets? Followed `mensia:match_object` all the way down to `ets:match_object` and that looks like a NIF so something I couldn't use outside of mnesia/ets/dets. https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/ets.erl#L262

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the closest you can get is using a compiled [match specification](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html), by calling the functions `ets:match_spec_compile` and `ets:match_spec_run`:

```
MS = ets:match_spec_compile([{{error, '_'}, [], ['$_']}]).
Items = [ok, {error, foo}, {error, bar}].
ets:match_spec_run(Items, MS).
```

This returns the two items in the `Items` list that match:

```
[{error,foo},{error,bar}]
```